# How to execute other Plug-in in my own Eclipse Plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I often do some sequential eclipse plugin-in operation for code quality,such as:pmd,checkstyle,findbug...

so,I would like to do following:

Create a own Eclipse Plug-in, that (for example) can integrate/execute these installed code quality plugin-in one by one.

is there a plug-in to do it?
or how to do implement the plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but there are no need for it :-)

You can add most of these systems as builders to your projects or your headless build - ant, PDEBuild or Tycho.